# Is it correct to invoke stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString of UIWebView in viewDidLoad?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I need to set the background of webView at a time when the html has not loaded.

In iOS 5.0 this code is correctly working:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.backgroundColor=\"#41414C\";"];
}
```

But in iOS 4.2 nothing happening with background.

How can I set background of web View at a time when the html has not loaded?

Comment: i am also using one local HTMLpage which contains javascript function.  But when i load it more than 2 or 3 it gets memory warning.. Any one have idea ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used webview:webViewDidFinishLoad method to evaluate javascript. It was working correctly in 4.2 but since I haven't tested it in iOS 5, I am not sure about its working in that version.

Answer (score 1):

- hide the webview until it is not loaded and set a view behind it with your desired background-color.
- when your webview is loaded, show it and set the background color of the html inside the webview