# UIWebView flickering in pushed ViewController

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers A and B controlled by UINavigationController. In B view controller I have UIWebView. I pass data form A to B. I push B view controller. And in B viewDidLoad method I set data to UIWebView. The loadHTMLString (which I use to set data) method in UIWebView controller is async so when  I push view controller B to UINavigatorController I see a little delay/blank screen/flickering because my data is still rendering in UIWebView despite B ViewController already pushed. So what is solution to avoid blank screen/flickering ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe hide webView `(webView.hidden = YES)` 
until `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` 
method (in this metod just set `webView.hidden = NO`) of `UIWebViewDelegate`  will be called, will be halpfull for you. Or, you can use `– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method for set background, its describes in this question [Is it correct to invoke stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString of UIWebView in viewDidLoad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678932/is-it-correct-to-invoke-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-of-uiwebview-in-v)